# Kernel Ridge Regression and RKHS

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, kernel-trick

Say you have $N$ observations of the function $F$. You want to predict the value of $F$ at an unknown point $x*$. Assume there is no noise in the observations. Given a kernel $K$, one is looking for solving the following equation where $H_K$ is the RKHS associated with the kernel $K$:

$\min_\limits{f\in H_K} ||f||^2_{H_K}$ with respect to $f(X_i) = F(X_i), \text{ for } i = 1, \ldots, N.$

We know the solution to this optimization problem through the representer theorem. So, here is my question: why do you want to minimize the norm? Why is the function with the minimal norm the "best" one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple reason: Because YOU have chosen this norm!
If the function is not the best one, you have chosen the wrong norm and the joke is on you.

Observe further, that in selecting a RKHS you have not only chosen the norm but also the function space, i.e. the candidate functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For your first point, why minimizing and not maximizing for instance?

Comment: Maximising does not help, since then solutions were not unique. Have a look at the proof of the representer theorem and you will see how minimisation ensures uniqueness of the solution.

Comment: Oh yes, right. Thank you.